# How two know if a NIC is connected to the internet

Tags: network-interface, route, iproute

I have two NICs on my device, eth0 and wlan0.

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# Wireless interface
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp

# Wired interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

route table

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.20.1    0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth0
default         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 wlan0
192.168.20.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.20.1    *               255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 eth0
192.168.100.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.100.1   *               255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 wlan0
```

How can I know if wlan0 or eth0 is connected to the internet?
If I `ping google.com` then it uses the default gateway, in this case is eth0. How can I know if wlan0 is connected to internet?
If I try `ping -I wlan0 google.com` it still uses the default gateway, only changes the source of the packets to be wlan0.
I could technically `ping google.com` keeping in mind which Iface is the default and then change the default Iface and then `ping google.com` again but that's pretty hacky.
I'm starting to explore the idea of multiple route tables. Will this help?

Thanks

Comment: `ping -I wlan0 google.com` can't use the default GW because they are on different networks. If it indeed used the default GW, no packets would ever return.

Comment: Why is there no response when using `ping -I wlan0 google.com`